# Stop Google Cloud Load Balancer

Tags: load-balancing, google-cloud-platform

Is there a way to stop/disable the Google Cloud Balancer?

I want to use it 8 hours a day, 5 days a week, only.

I can stop the instances but I can't stop the load balancer.

The idea here is to lower the charges.

The only way that I've found is to delete the load balancer and I will lose all the configurations.

Answer (score 2):

To stop the charges for load balancing, you need to [delete the forwarding rules](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/using-forwarding-rules#deleting-fr) and/or [delete the load balancers themselves](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https#deleting_individual_resources).

Remember, Google Cloud charges for forwarding rules whether they are created for load balancing, and for most load balancing use cases, you need only one forwarding rule per load balancer.

I might consider the low cost vs delete the load balancing:

The following examples use US pricing:
For example, if you create one forwarding rule, you are charged $0.025/hour. Entire weekend =0.025 x 64 hours =  1.6 USD
(Just for forwarding rules, it suppose no traffic because you have the VM instance stopped).

It is on the [GCP's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/network-pricing#load_balancing_ingress_and_egress_charges)

Keep safe.

Comment: It makes sense what you said. But If I could use it 5 days a week, and 8 hours a day, it will be 160 hours * 0.025 = ~ 4 USD. If I use it 24 hours for 30 days, it will be 720 hours * 0.025 = ~18 USD. It is a huge difference. I will be using 3 load balancers. If I delete the rule I will lose its configuration...

Comment: I agree, that's why you should consider spend this 14 USd versus lose the configuration and recreate every day your forwarding rule.  No way to disable or stop the LB.

Comment: Losing the configuration and recreate it every day shouldn't be a problem since I am using Terraform. But still not the best practice/solution. I will try to contact GCP support and see if there's something else I can do. Thanks for your help! :)