# Temporarily disable gcp load balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, google-compute-engine

When trying to test the HTTP to HTTPS feature present in the Load Balancer configuration, I found out that it wasn't present while editing the Load Balancer I have. I made a new one just to see if I had something different from the guide/example given in the documentation (I used the exact same "components" as in the other Load balancer, minus the names) and the option was there. I went ahead and tried to applied it, but the static IP I have clashed with the one in use.

Now, I need to ***test*** this before actually using it. I cannot use a separate static IP nor a different Compute Engine due budget constraints (We are at a very early stage of our product, I can't just deploy a new VM for this). The best option I have is to take down the current working LB and do my testing, but that's the only way we provide our service.

Then comes the question: Can I just "turn off" my current load balancer while I check the new one? If not, do I have to delete my LB in use and then redo it MANUALLY? I want to believe there is an option somewhere in the panel or in the CLI (Other than undoing actions) to avoid this. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Tried to replicate but still unable to to stop Load Balancer and the only option was to delete the Load Balancer. I see some previous issue like this ([Stop Google Cloud Load Balancer](https://serverfault.com/questions/1050814/stop-google-cloud-load-balancer)) and the only way was to delete to minimize [costs](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/network-pricing#lb).

You can also consider/review using [Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/security-policy-overview) policies to Control Traffic on your Load Balancers. But still the [cost](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/network-pricing#armor-pricing) will be based on what you are using.

By [Configuring Cloud Armor Policies](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/configure-security-policies#configuring_security_policies_for), the external IP will still open to the clients but Load Balancers will respond with the error code you configured and will not forward request to the Backend VMs.

Comment: Cost is a concern, but I would need a second IP AFAIK to use Cloud Armor in this, rigth? Kind of a shame it's the only way to do this at this time. I'll keep an eye around discusions on this, as I think this "toggle" feature is useful enough

Comment: No need for other IP using Cloud Armor. It's a policy which will allow, deny, or redirect requests to your external HTTP(S) load balancer. Kindly consider upvoting answer if you find it useful/helped on your end.

Comment: Sorry, was a bit off during the holidays. I didn't checked out Armor, but I will since I'm interested in the CDN feature as well. I managed to keep the site alive by using two front ends, one in 443 and the other in 80. Thank you for the links and the info. Happy new year.